# Is there a way to combine two union queries into one single query based on particular conditions?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have 2 tables with below format

```
     TableA                             TableB
ID1  Name    Date                    ID1   Status
1    abc   April 2000                1     open
2    xyz   May 2000                  2     closed
3    def   March 2016                3     closed
4    pqr   March 2016                4     open
```

With the below query

```
SELECT a.id1,
       a.name,
       a.date,
       b.status
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON a.id1=b.id2
AND b.status='open'
UNION
SELECT a.id1,
       a.name,
       a.date,
       b.status
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON a.id1=b.id2
AND b.status='closed'
AND a.date>'April 2014'
```

I get the below result set

```
a.id1  a.name  a.date       b.status
1      abc     April 2000   open
3      def     March 2016   closed
4      pqr     March 2016    open
```

My intention is to display all the open status and last 2 years of closed status for a given ID.
So my question is, can we write this query in one single query to get all the open and last 2 years of closed status?
Please suggest.

Comment: your date comparison if faulty,'April 2014' and 'March 2016' are strings, so string compare thinks 'March' > 'April'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm rewrite you queries in single query.

```
select a.id1, a.name, a.date, b.status
  from TableA a
  join TableB b
    on a.id1 = b.id2
 where (b.status = 'closed' and a.date > 'April 2014')
    or b.status = 'open'
```